# Why to avoid in-page <script>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, model-view-controller

When dealing with the structure of javascript in a website. Currently i try to seperate all my   javascript into files, something like app.js.

Although is it better just to place scripts on the actual page they appear, with  tags? and if so what are the reasons?

Comment: The browser is happy with either.

Comment: You should bundle and minify all of your scripts, clumping them into single files (if possible). That way, you only make the minimal number of requests and browsers can cache them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is to place your script files in an external file.  The [Yahoo Developer](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#external) site also calls for this:

> Using external files in the real world generally produces faster pages
>   because the JavaScript and CSS files are cached by the browser.
>   JavaScript and CSS that are inlined in HTML documents get downloaded
>   every time the HTML document is requested. This reduces the number of
>   HTTP requests that are needed, but increases the size of the HTML
>   document. On the other hand, if the JavaScript and CSS are in external
>   files cached by the browser, the size of the HTML document is reduced
>   without increasing the number of HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

To do not forget Wordpress in this post, you should know that this CMS has requirements concerning the call of javascript files : always have `wp_head()`  just before the closing `</head>` and have `wp_footer()` just before the closing `</body>`

This is in the case you call your external files  using the `<script>` tag. But in Wordpress the best way is to  enqueue it using: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script